# SQL Server performance and no join predicate problem are linked?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I'm going to be nuts with this problem.
I am working on 3 servers. I used the same databases everywhere, thanks to the backup and restore options.
The problem is that on one server the query duration is very high (8 minutes) beside the two others (less than 1 second). The query execution plan is also different and I really don't know why.

Here is the query I test :

```
SELECT * FROM TRACK_TEMP2.dbo.[c96a83ff-3cdb-4a03-b118-df3eff591c27] 
WHERE 
TRACK_TEMP2.dbo.[c96a83ff-3cdb-4a03-b118-df3eff591c27].[Gg] 
    NOT IN (
            SELECT [TTop_FullPath] FROM [TH].[dbo].[VTopicCompatibility]
                    WHERE TTop_Type=(
                                   SELECT TTop_Name FROM [TH].[dbo].[TTopic]
                                    WHERE TTOP_PK_ID=   1237936 )
           ) 
 AND 
NOT TRACK_TEMP2.dbo.[c96a83ff-3cdb-4a03-b118-df3eff591c27].[Gg] IS NULL
```

Here is the execution plan I get on a fast server:
[image: execution plan fast server]

Here is the execution plan I get on a slow server:
[image: execution plan slow server]

Here is the details on the warnings:
[image: warnings details]

I cannot understand why there is such a difference. Any idea ?

PS : if I remove the last line and the "and" it is very fast.

Comment: Can you try changing `AND 
NOT TRACK_TEMP2.dbo.[c96a83ff-3cdb-4a03-b118-df3eff591c27].[Gg] IS NULL` to `AND 
TRACK_TEMP2.dbo.[c96a83ff-3cdb-4a03-b118-df3eff591c27].[Gg] IS NOT NULL`.. may or may not make a difference? They could be different plans due to different configs (parallelism threshold), old statistics or a cached bad plan

Comment: The last condition is unnecessary (but hopefully SQL Server can figure it out on its own).

Comment: IS NOT NULL does not change anything for the plan neither the duration

Comment: the last condition IS necessary !

Comment: Why this "No Join Predicate" ?

Comment: `[TH].[dbo].[VTopicCompatibility]` is a view. Compare the definitions between the servers; I'd be willing to bet you'll see a difference (and/or a difference between the contents/indexes of the tables involved). Also, there's [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for execution plans -- much more comfortable than deciphering pictures (or reading French -- today I learned execution plans are localizable!)

Comment: I assume you get the same number of records and same results between all executions? If you remove the last line do you get the same or different results? Removing the last line might simply cause it to use a new (better) query plan, which would imply that the bad plan is simply cached and needs to be removed.